# Powershell как увеличить шрифт?

Tags: шрифты, powershell

Подскажите пожалуйста, как увеличить текст в кавычках, например у меня есть:

`$Title ="ED503: Конверт для передачи финансовых сообщений о переводе денежных средств.                        $EDNo="Номер ЭС в течение опердня: "                                                                           $EDDate="Дата составления ЭС: "`                                                                          
`$finnely = ($Title + $InitialED_EDNo + $EDDate)`
`$finnely  | Out-Printer "\\msk-prn\Kyocera3"`

Как мне увеличить текст в кавычках при выводе на печать ?

Пробовал `$psISE.Options.FontSize = 15` - не помогает, меняется только размер в программе, но не текста...

Comment: Просто нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по заголовку окна PowerShell, и измените размер шрифта в Свойствах.

Comment: Создайте документ word или pdf с нужным шрифтом и отправляйте его на печать.

Comment: @HumanNo1 К сожалению, это тоже самое что и $psISE.Options.FontSize = 15,  - а она не помогает, меняется только размер в программе но не текста при выводе на печать.

Comment: @user7860670 У вас не будет примера ? Возможно это хороший вариант.

Comment: @user7860670 добавил строчку $finnely | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\kadaev\Desktop\TestTest\test.txt'    А как теперь изменить размер в том файле автоматически и отправить на печать?)

Comment: Сохранять имеет смысл в какой-то формат с форматированием, а не просто текст. Можно попробовать  postscript, html, rtf, tex с последующим преобразованием в pdf